# Why is 2's compliment used when doing binary subtraction?

Tags: binary

Hi guys im just a little bit confused with binary subtraction. I have the following doubts:

```
1) Why not just subtract normally(subtracting two binary number without converting to any other form) using binary numbers? 
2) Why cant we use singed numbers to subtract, why wont it work? 
3) Why is 2's compliment used?
```

Comment: What are you talking about?  What does "subtract normally" mean?

Comment: Edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: If you use 2s compliment, you can substitue substraction by addition, so a-b == a + (-b) with -b being in 2s compliment representation.

Also creating 2s compliment is simple (invert and add 1). So all is reduced to addition.

Answer (score 0):

2s complement is a way to represent numbers as negative. by converting, for example 0011 to 2s complement, you get 1101. When you add the two's complement, you get the correct answer in a way that is easy for the computer to calculate with present hardware.

For example, 0100 (4) - 0011 (3)  would require a subtraction piece of hardware, but 0010 + 1101 (the two's complement of 0011) gets 1111. 2s complementing that gets 0001, which is the correct answer.

When designing a processor, you can use the same ALU that only does adding, and convert the second number to 2s complement (which is trivial compared to an ADD, and effectively renders it as the negative of itself) and thus reuse the one ADD component, rather than making a second component to subtract in some other fashion.

Basically, 2s complement is a guaranteed way to represent -x when given x. Adding -x lets you better utilize your addition hardware.

Comment: Neither is "harder" than the other.  But the two's-complement approach potentially saves hardware if you already have an addition circuit.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the problem of how to represent signed numbers.

An alternative is one complement, where the highest bit acts as sign too.

Adding 4 and -3 in one complement:

```
0000 0100
1111 1100
```

The same in two complement

```
0000 0100
1111 1101
```

To get the desired 0000 0001 is much easier in two complement. Easier in the sense of needing less gates to implement the computation logic.